How to change the format of 1st and 5th date column from 28-MAR-2024 to 03/28/2024
Example Input File
AsofDate,Portfolio,Shock,CUSIP,DATE,BALANCE,INTEREST,SCHED_PRIN,UNSCHED_PRIN,LOSS
28-MAR-2024,INV,DN50,28623RAE8,22-APR-2024,25000000,447380,0,0,0
28-MAR-2024,INV,DN50,28623RAE8,22-JUL-2024,25000000,413892,0,0,0
28-MAR-2024,INV,DN50,28623RAE8,21-OCT-2024,25000000,399624.25,0,0,0
28-MAR-2024,INV,DN50,28623RAE8,21-JAN-2025,25000000,386169.5,0,0,0

Lets say above is my input file, I would like to change the format of 1st (AsofDate) and 5th (DATE) column date form from dd-MMM-YYYY (Example: 28-MAR-2024) to mm/dd/YYYY (Example: 03/28/2024).
Tried the below command for 1st column,
awk -F',' '{gsub(/"/,"",$1); cmd="date -d\""$1"\" +\\\"%m/%d/%Y\\\""; cmd |getline $1; close(cmd); print >FILENAME }' OFS=, $FILE

The problem with this command is, its taking more time to process. The file size is 26000KB and I need to iterate for all the files under a directory. How to modify this command to achieve better performance or efficiency?

Which flavour of AWK?  I suspect GNU AWK might be helpful here.

You probably need to stop creating date processes on each line of input.  I suggest you try running a single date -f and communicating with it as a coprocess.

please update the question to show the expected output (corresponding to the sample input)

Consider changing your dates to the ISO 6801 standard format YYYY-MM-DD instead of the ambiguous, unsortable format you have in mind so they're easier to work with (e.g. sort, select in a range, compare, etc.) in future. So instead of output like 03/06/2024 which is ambiguous (could be March 6 or could be June 3) and unsortable, you'd have 2024-03-06 if its March 6 or 2024-06-03 if it's June 3.

OP's current code takes so long to run because of the repeated calls out to the OS to have date reformat the date fields.  We can eliminate these expensive OS/date calls with some simple splitting and reformatting of the date fields.
Assumptions:

data fields do not contain embedded commas, ie, commas only show up as delimiters

One awk idea:
awk '

function reformat(_date, c) {
    split(_date,c,"-")                             # split _date on "-", place parts in array c[]
    return map[c[2]] "/" c[1] "/" c[3]             # return parts in desired format
}

BEGIN { FS = OFS = ","
        split("JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC",a)
        for (i in a)
            map[a[i]] = sprintf("%02d",i)          # convert a[1]=JAN to map[JAN]=01
      }

FNR>1 { $1 = reformat($1)                          # skip header line; replace $1 with new date format
        $5 = reformat($5)                          # replace $5 with new date format
      }
1                                                  # print current line
' sample.file

This generates:
AsofDate,Portfolio,Shock,CUSIP,DATE,BALANCE,INTEREST,SCHED_PRIN,UNSCHED_PRIN,LOSS
03/28/2024,INV,DN50,28623RAE8,04/22/2024,25000000,447380,0,0,0
03/28/2024,INV,DN50,28623RAE8,07/22/2024,25000000,413892,0,0,0
03/28/2024,INV,DN50,28623RAE8,10/21/2024,25000000,399624.25,0,0,0
03/28/2024,INV,DN50,28623RAE8,01/21/2025,25000000,386169.5,0,0,0


This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -E '1{x;s/^/JAN01FEB02MAR03APR04MAY05JUN06JUL07AUG08SEP09OCT10NOV11DEC12/;x}
        G;:a;s#(..)-(...)-(....,.*\n.*\2(..))#\4/\1/\3#;ta;P;d' file

Prep the hold space with a calendar lookup on the first line.
Append the lookup table.
Using iteration, pattern matching and back references, manipulate each line as desired.
Print the first line only and delete the remainder.
